# Specify relationships between protocols in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I want to specify a protocol that manages some type objects that conform to another protocol. Like this:

```
// Specify protocol
protocol ElementGenerator {
    func getElements() -> [Element]
}
protocol Element {
    // ...
}

// Implement
class FooElementGenerator: ElementGenerator {
    func getElements() -> [FooElement] {
        // Generate elements here
        return [FooElement()]
    }
}
class FooElement {
    // ...
}
```

When trying to compile this, I get an error:

```
Type 'FooElementGenerator' does not conform to protocol 'ElementGenerator'
```

hinting that candidate `func getElements() -> [FooElement]` has non-matching type of `() -> [FooElement]`, but instead it expects `() -> [Element]`.

How this kind of an error can be fixed?

**UPDATE:**

This solution seems to be working:

```
protocol ElementGenerator {
    typealias T:Element

    func getElements() -> [T]
}

protocol Element {
    // ...
}


class FooElementGenerator: ElementGenerator {
    typealias T = FooElement

    func getElements() -> [T] {
        return [T()]
    }
}

class FooElement: Element {
    // ...
}
```

But when I try to create a variable like this:

```
let a: ElementGenerator = FooElementGenerator()
```

a new error appears:

```
Protocol 'ElementGenerator' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When implementing protocol methods, the return type must be same but you may return child class object like this;

```
protocol ElementGenerator {
    func getElements() -> [Element]
}

//@objc for bridging in objective C
@objc protocol Element {
    // ...
}

// Implement
class FooElementGenerator: NSObject,ElementGenerator {

    override init() {
        super.init();
        //--
        let fooElements:[FooElement] = self.getElements() as! [FooElement]
    }

    func getElements() -> [Element] {
        // Generate elements here
        return [FooElement()]
    }
}

class FooElement:NSObject, Element {
    // ...
    override init() {
        super.init();
        //--
        NSLog("FooElement init");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. I guess I was thinking about too complicated thing so I missed this simple idea.

Answer (score 0):

The error message in the second case is given since you have defined `ElementGenerator` with an “Associated Type”, and this means that you can only use it in giving constraints for types.

For instance, if you need to have a function defined for generic `ElementGenerator` values, you could write something like this:

```
func f<T1:ElementGenerator>(elemGenerator:T1) -> Element {
  return elemGenerator.getElements()[0]
}

var a : Element = FooElementGenerator()
var b : Element = BarElementGenerator()

var x : Element = f(a)
var y : Element = f(b)

var z : FooElement = f(a) as! FooElement
```